# Attach image to the text sent by the Telegram bot via google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram, telegram-bot

My current script is:

```
function EnviarTelegram(botSecret, chatId, body) {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendMessage?text=" + encodeURIComponent(body) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

The formula in Google Sheets I use to send the message is:

```
=EnviarTelegram("Code to Bot","Code to ChatId","Lista de jogos na TV 

<a href='https://www.google.com/testtesttesttest'>CLIQUE AQUI E ACESSE JÁ</a>")
```

I would like to be able to create a message with an image join to the text, like this:

[image]

The image link I want to use is this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/testestest

Is there a way to attach the image to the text?

Comment: When your shared image is used, for example, `=EnviarTelegram("Code to Bot","Code to ChatId","sample text 1\n<img src='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IztJm_pxa-ZaPfg7Ki9NU2z9vmqczjDy&export=download'>\nsample text 2")` using `parse_mode=markdown`? Or, how about `=EnviarTelegram("Code to Bot","Code to ChatId","sample text 1 ![](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IztJm_pxa-ZaPfg7Ki9NU2z9vmqczjDy&export=download) sample text 2")` using `parse_mode=markdown`? But I'm not sure whether these are the same direction you expect. So I proposed it as a comment. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `/sendMessage` method.

If you wish to send an image, with an optional *caption*, use the [`sendPhoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) method.

Your function could become something like so;

```js
function EnviarTelegram(botSecret, chatId, photoUrl, caption) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendPhoto?caption=" + encodeURIComponent(caption) + "&photo=" + encodeURIComponent(photoUrl) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

```
=EnviarTelegram("Code to Bot","Code to ChatId", "https://example.com/image.jog", "Lista de jogos na TV 

<a href='https://www.google.com/testtesttesttest'>CLIQUE AQUI E ACESSE JÁ</a>")
```

Comment: Thanks for support mate. I already found two small errors in answear, change ```caption``` to ```body```and before ```Lista```, you need to have a ```"``` in the formula, the result is ```"Lista...```. If you already want to edit the answer by modifying this details.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! Forgot to replace those param names, the missing `"` was caused by copy/pasting error. I've fixed those errors in my answer!

Comment: Yes my friend. I'll put the vote and mark it as the best answer, I'm just doing tests to make sure it's working perfectly and that it has been solved.